# Does okta support user resolving?

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am testing OKTA api-users, and I’m interested about a specific capability that I couldn’t find. I want to be able to attach to the request 100 id’s and get back an array of the user objects of these id’s(just like api/v1/users/{id} API,but for many ids), Is there an API of OKTA that can do it(maybe some post request that receives in body the ids and returns the user objects?) ?

I was able to make a workaround, by using the GET api/v1/users API with query parameters(filter/search) but I didn’t find it to be the best solution because the URL can’t be too long(I had to put 100 ids to the search parameter).

Thanks

Comment: I believe it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing would be to use a `search` or `filter` param:
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#list-users-with-a-filter

`/api/v1/users?filter=id eq "id1" or id eq "id2"`

Which for 100 params would be too long, as you noticed.

In true StackOverflow fashion, don't do A, do B. (sorry). You have a few options, but it depends on what you are doing.
If you are always querying the same set of users, you could add a custom attribute to your set of users:

`/api/v1/users?search=profile.favOneHundred eq "true"`

The other options are use case-specific, can you let us know what you are trying to do with those 100 users, and maybe we offer up an alternative?